# % Processor Time / _Total performance counter on Windows 2022 wildly incorrect?

Tags: windows

I've seen various posts about the the % Processor Time / _Total performance counter being slightly inconsistent with CPU usage, but in my case it's off by a factor of about 10:

[image: Performance counters]
[image: Task manager]

When I checked 10 minutes later, it was more normal, but I can't explain this anomaly.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So lets dive in. And please change the title to "Windows Server 2022" instead of "12".

The Processor Object in the perfomance counter gives us a complete details on how our processor that is driving our computer is being used. If you are using a Multi Core processor you will see the instances of the each and every core of the server, and selecting the appropriate counter we can even calculate on how each individual CPU is being utilized. Be aware of the median counters when using _total counters.

% Processor Time is the percentage of elapsed time that the processor spends to execute a non-Idle thread. It is calculated by measuring the percentage of time that the processor spends executing the idle thread and then subtracting that value from 100%. (Each processor has an idle thread that consumes cycles when no other threads are ready to run). This counter is the primary indicator of processor activity, and displays the average percentage of busy time observed during the sample interval. It should be noted that the accounting calculation of whether the processor is idle is performed at an internal sampling interval of the system clock (10ms). On todays fast processors, % Processor Time can therefore underestimate the processor utilization as the processor may be spending a lot of time servicing threads between the system clock sampling interval. Workload based timer applications are one example  of applications  which are more likely to be measured inaccurately as timers are signaled just after the sample is taken.

% Processor Time is the percentage of elapsed time that all of process threads used the processor to execution instructions. An instruction is the basic unit of execution in a computer, a thread is the object that executes instructions, and a process is the object created when a program is run. Code executed to handle some hardware interrupts and trap conditions are included in this count.

Now this Processor time counter under the Process Object gives the amount of CPU this Process is taking individually. This value is calculated over the base line of (No of Logical CPUS * 100),  So this is going to be a calculated over a baselin of more than 100.

Lets think you are using a QUADCore System, so the baseline over which this Value is going to be calculated is 400. So now if we run the Datacollector Set and capture all the Process and sort them by the order of their Processor time, we will come up with the Process that is taking the most CPU in the server.

There may come up a condition that this Value is more than 400 ie. more than (No of Logical CPUS * 100) this indicates that the Process is extensively using Multithreading and using the Processor to more than its capacity.

Answer (score 0):

Task Manager shows since Windows 8 in the CPU graph not `% Processor Time` but `% Processor Utility`.

- Processor Utility is the amount of work a processor is completing, as a percentage of the amount of work the processor could complete if it were running at its nominal performance and never idle. On some processors, Processor Utility may exceed 100%.

This was added to reflect Intel Speedstep where the CPU and over or underclock dynamically. If your 3 GHz CPU downclocks to 700 MHz then you are running about 4 times slower but your workload needs longer to execute because of the lower CPU frequency. But this might be more energy efficient if only light CPU load is on your system.
Still this is highly confusing and also in my opinion meaningless.

[image]

The picture above shows a workload which uses up to 23 cores of a 24 cores machine. Task manager shows the 100% capped value of `% Processor Utility` to not confuse users, although the actual value will reach 151%. What you and every other user on this planet wants to see is `% Processor Utility` but MS thinks otherwise.

More complaints are linked here:

- https://aaron-margosis.medium.com/task-managers-cpu-numbers-are-all-but-meaningless-2d165b421e43
- https://illuminati.services/2021/03/17/windows-10-task-manager-cpu-inaccurate-a-tale-of-two-metrics/

Still a factor 10 is too much to be explained by this. Did you run some HyperV workload on your machine? I am not sure how these are reflected in all performance counters. Some seem to include the CPU from VMs while others don't.